# Autoincrement with SQL Insert

Tags: c#, sql-server

There were some previous questions like this but I didn't really understand the answers.  Here's my query

```
using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "INSERT INTO Results VALUES(@ResultID, @HasSucceeded, @ScenarioID, @Screenshot)",
    conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ResultID", Id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HasSucceeded", HasSucceeded);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ScenarioID", Id);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Screenshot", screenshot);

    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Now I am using `Id` as a placeholder to for `@ResultID`.  What I really want to do is `autoincrement` `@ResultID` with this `INSERT INTO` query.  How can I do this?

Comment: As an aside, I doubt this code would ever get past me if I did a review on it. Specify the column names, not just the values, in the INSERT statement. You can thank me later. `;)` (If anything ever happens to the table structure that makes it incompatible with what your code assumes, you'll get an exception rather than potentially data inserted into unexpected columns.)

Comment: Just use an IDENTITY column: problem solved (you don't tell it the value to insert: it does that itself)

Comment: @MarcGravell I'm not sure that helps the OP if the value is needed later, though. Though, if that's the case, that's where a stored procedure starts being called for. (It might be called for anyway, but especially then...)

Comment: @Michael you just get the new value out via either SCOPE_IDENTITY(), or the new-ish insert-with-output construct: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx - not a problem at all. The latter is mainly for multi-row inserts; for single row inserts SCOPE_IDENTITY() is ideal

Comment: @MarcGravell As long as you are in the same scope yes, but will you be after `ExecuteNonQuery()`? Or can you use `ExecuteScalar()` for that? Anyway, that's answer and not comment territory IMO.

Comment: Answer to the next question: Use [`Scope_Identity()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190315.aspx) or an [`Output` clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) to get the value assigned. It's worth learning about `Output` since it can handle multiple rows and both before and after values (when applicable). It's helpful to tag database questions with the database software and version, e.g. `sql-server-2008`.

Comment: @michael you know you can put more than one statement in commandtext, right?

Comment: @MarcGravell Actually no, but that makes sense. The system I work on (C# + MS SQL) uses SPs throughout, together with return values and output parameters as appropriate, so quite frankly it's never been an issue for me. I still feel you should write down your comments in an answer, though; I'd probably upvote it.

Comment: @Michael done - I was trying to avoid it, as not at a PC :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make this an IDENTITY column (for example, IDENTITY(1,1)) and let the database manage it. Trying to manage it from outside is a threading nightmare. Then it becomes (noting that it is unusually complicated due to using Id for 2 columns, which sound like an error):

```
int newId = 0;

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    @"INSERT INTO Results (HasSucceeded, Screenshot)
      VALUES (@HasSucceeded, @Screenshot);
      DECLARE @ResultID int = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
      UPDATE Results SET ScenarioID = @ResultID
                     WHERE ResultID = @ResultID;
      SELECT @ResultID;", conn))
{
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@HasSucceeded", HasSucceeded);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Screenshot", screenshot);

    newId = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
}

// ...Use newId here...
```

Comment: While I agree that this should be an identity, if it is not and there is other code inserting to this table (from this application, from other applicatiosn or from data imports), then you could cause it to break.